# Rebend Violin bow

Tags: violin, maintenance, bow

According to [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/57829/38312) answer, one can 'reheat and rebend' a violin bow. I have an old bow (poor-quality, it is weighted badly and needs rehairing) that is very slack and I'm guessing needs rebending.

I don't really want to take it to a luthier, since it's not really worth it, and I can only find tutorials for rebending *warped* bows (that twist to the *side*, which mine does not)

How can I rebend my bow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't guess.  Slack has nothing to do with bow-bend and everything to do with the age of the hair or even the skill with which it was last rehaired.  If it's really not weighted the way you want, why bother with it at all in the first place?

How do you know what it's worth if you haven't taken it to a luthier?

I can guarantee that  any attempt on your part to rebend in any axis will lead to disaster.  My recommendation is that you bring it to a luthier or reputable string instrument store and either get it repaired or sell it to them.